# When to use `use` or the fully qualified name

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm wondering when to use the fully qualified class name or when to put a `use` statement on top of the class.
For example:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ImageStatus extends Model {
    public function image(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo( \App\Image::class, 'id' );
    }

    public function user(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo( \App\User::class, 'id' );
    }
}
```

At the moment I have this piece of code and my PHPStorm tells me `Unnecessary fully qualified name`. This hint disappears when I change it to:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class ImageStatus extends Model {
    public function image(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo( \App\Image::class, 'id' );
    }

    public function user(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo( \App\User::class, 'id' );
    }
}
```

So I'm wondering what the difference is, performance wise, code readability and if one is better than the other.

Comment: code reeadability wise, I always opt for using `use` as it means you declare all your needed classes under namespace, then you can use them wherever instead of having to type out the full class name each time you want to init it

Comment: using use Increase readability and is useful when you have to use particular class more than once. BTW using use is also a standard convention. Fully qualified  can be used to resolve the conflict like when there is same class name.

Comment: So using `use` doesn't affect performance in any way?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `use SomeNamespace\ClassName` than you do not have later append `\SomeNamespace` to `ClassName`. So your example should be

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;

class ImageStatus extends Model {
    public function image(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(Image::class, 'id' );
    }

    public function user(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id' );
    }
}
```

Please note that when you are in same namespace, than you do not need to add namespace to class name. When `namespace App;` then `User::class` instead of `\App\User::class`